# Procedure for using gdb to examine output and error messages returned by a called program

Tags: gdb

I've got a program written in C++ which has a function that looks similar to this:

```
std::string cmd = "curl -s http://x.x.x.x/latest/meta-data/public-hostname";
std::vector<std::string> output;
runCmd(cmd, output);
```

If the curl command fails the program silently ignores it. I need to be able to examine what's happening when the program gets to this point: I'd like to look at the output generated by `curl`, including error message and return code.

How do I do this with gdb? Please walk me through the steps of running the program with gdb so I can see what's happening with `curl`. It's a fairly large program. I am only interested in this particular function call, I want to ignore everything else up to that point.

i should note that I don't have the environment to compile the code. All I've got is the binary.

Comment: Try this : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/gnu_debugger/

Comment: `strace -f -s 1024 -o log ./program` should do this.

Comment: I was thinking strace would work if it had an option to not truncate the command output (it truncates by default).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure gdb will help you much as you spawn a sub process.
I would suggest changing the code to

```
std::string cmd = "curl -s http://x.x.x.x/latest/meta-data/public-hostname 2>/tmp/error | tee /tmp/output";
```

so that /tmp/erro and /tmp/output gives you what happened;

EDIT:
as compilation os not possible, you may use this trick:
create a script named `curl` containing:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/curl $@ 2>/tmp/error | tee /tmp/output
```

(don't forget to change permission to +x)

then, when executing your program just do:

```
PATH=.:$PATH ./yout_binary
```

assuming your script is in .

then the program will use your 'fake' curl

Comment: Unfortunately it's not my code and I don't have the environment to compile it, so I need to be able to use strace or gdb to get what I want.

Comment: then use `strace -f` yo would be able to track everything, but you'll have some manual search in the verbose output. Nevertheless, I still believe that gdb will not be very helpful

Comment: strace will work if it has the option to not truncate what is printed. .... your suggestion on the fake curl is good.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `strace` for this task, rather then gdb:

```
strace -f -s 1024 -o log ./program
```

Here `-f` mean to trace child processes as well. You need it because this line of code `runCmd(cmd, output);` most likely does `fork()` to run child process.

`-s 1024` specifies maximum string size to print. By default it is `32` which is often too short.

Once you save the output to `log` file, you should easealy find something like `curl -s` in it. This is where the child process starts. You can see what it writes to stderr or stdout in lines like `write(2, "...` or `write(1, "...`. At the end of the process execution you will see it's exit code, for example `1` exit code:

```
exit_group(1)                           = ?
```

Comment: I've taken this suggestion. I'm not seeing any curl statements in the output. strace doesn't show function calls, does it? I'm curious to whether this particular function (the one that has the runCmd in it) is being reached or not.

Comment: No, strace does not show C++ function calls. It only shows kernel system calls. You should see `execve("/usr/bin/curl", ...` system call if curl is indeed called.

Comment: it turns out this particular function is never called, there's another place in the code that bypasses it.